# Calculate the number of users based on the below conditions by writing a single query SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

There are two campaigns running campaign A and Campaign B and list of user ids participated in those two campaign is given below. **Calculate the number of users** based on the below conditions by **writing a single query**.

1. Participated in campaign A
2. Participated in campaign B
3. Participated in campaign A only
4. Participated in campaign B only
5. Participated in both the campaigns
6. Participated in either campaign A or Campaign B

```
  Campaign A    Campaign B
    user_id     user_id
    91          62
    27          11
    58          16
    50          92
    64          17
    65          71
    54          12
    98          37
    78          93
    24          58
    31          54
    73          94
    63          85
    72          30
    94          32
    20          1
    38          48
    8           99
    43          45
    33          46
    26          39
    100         29
    61          49
    87          73
    84          81
    15          88
    80          70
    77          33
    40          55
    82          
    42          
    56          
    95          
    88
```

I am not able to figure out how to write in single SQL query.

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.  Also, what does the source table look like?

Comment: you can just use a `UNION` to unify the result of N queries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have two different tables, you can use `union all` and aggregation:

```
select in_a, in_b, count(*) as num_users
from ((select user_id, 1 as in_a, 0 as in_b
       from a
      ) union all
      (select user_id, 0 as in_a, 1 as in_b
       from b
      )
     ) u
group by in_a, in_b;
```

This gives you all the information you need.  You can use `group by in_a, in_b with rollup` to get all combinations.

Or, you can summarize this into one row:

```
select sum(in_a) as in_a, sum(in_b) as in_b,
       sum(in_a * (1 - in_b)) as in_a_only,
       sum(in_b * (1 - in_a)) as in_b_only,
       sum(in_a * in_b) as in_ab
from ((select user_id, 1 as in_a, 0 as in_b
       from a
      ) union all
      (select user_id, 0 as in_a, 1 as in_b
       from b
      )
     ) u;
```

Note:  These both assume that users are unique in each campaign.  If not, just use `select distinct` or `union` in the subquery.

Comment: What does this mean? @Strawberry